# Creating a chart and then adding a range from where to take the data labels

Tags: excel, vba

I've got the following code

```
range_data_labels = "E" & lrow2 + 1 & ":" & "E" & lrow3
  
'Add data labels
   ActiveChart.ApplyDataLabels
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange. _
    InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, range_data_labels, 0
Selection.ShowRange = True
Selection.ShowValue = False
```

and I know that the following line doesn't work because I've got "range_data_labels" on it, I'm just not sure on what format I am supposed to include this if I don't want a set range all of the time.

```
    InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, range_data_labels, 0
```

Ps: in my example, range_data_labels = E9:E13 but it will vary depending on some inputs of my code.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.textrange2.insertchartfield), the second parameter (formula)

> Specifies a cell (or range) if the msoChartFieldFormula constant is
> passed in for the ChartFieldType parameter.

You have passed `msoChartFieldRange`, which

> Specifies the value of a range of data.

as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/library-reference/msochartfieldtype-enumeration-office).

So as I understand this, and since the formula is a string, you should pass a string representation of the range. In a hard-coded example, "Sheet1!E9:E13".

For something more dynamic and if `range_data_labels` is a `Range` object, then use either `range_data_labels.Address` or `range_data_labels.AddressLocal`. The latter is probably preferred.

[Range.Address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address)

> Returns a String value that represents the range reference in the
> language of the macro.

[Range.AddressLocal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.addresslocal)

> Returns the range reference for the specified range in the language of
> the user. Read-only String.

Comment: I did the following, but it is still not taking my range as the range for the labels    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange. _
        InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, range_data_labels.Address, 0

Comment: Are you getting an error? What is happening exactly? Please edit your post with details of the chart, the data, the code, the error message (if any).